# how to get the raw version of a template string in iojs

Tags: node.js, v8, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to get the raw version of a template string in iojs ?

```
var s = `foo${1+1}bar`
console.log(s); // foo2bar
```

In the previous example I would like to get the string: `foo${1+1}bar`

*edit1*:
My need is to detect whether a template string depends on its context of if is is just a 'constant' string that may contain CR and LF

Comment: You cannot. Why do you want that?

Comment: only by using `'` or `"`.

Comment: thefourtheye, see my *edit1*

Comment: Yes, you can get the raw version of the string parts by tagging the template string, but `1+1` will have been evaluated to  `2` already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the raw version of a template string in iojs ?

No it is not. It's not possible to get the raw representation of the literal, just like there is no way to get the "raw" literal in these cases:

```
var foo = {[1+1]: 42};
var bar = 1e10;
var baz = "\"42\"";
```

Note that the term "template string" is misleading (as it may indicate that you could somehow get the raw value of the string (which is also not the case as shown above)). The correct term is ["template literal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-template-literal-lexical-components)".

> My need is to detect whether a template string depends on its context of if is is just a 'constant' string that may contain CR and LF

Seems like a job for a static analysis tool. E.g. you can use [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast) to parse the source code and traverse all template literals.

For example, [the AST representation of `` `foo${1+1}bar` `` is](http://felix-kling.de/esprima_ast_explorer/#/kwLFqI60mf):

[image]

If such an AST node as an empty `expression` property, then you know that the value is constant.

---

There is a way to determine whether a template literal is "static" or "dynamic" at runtime, but that involves changing the behavior of the code.

You can use **tagged** templates. Tagged templates are functions that get passed the static and dynamic portions of a template literal.

Example:

```
function foo(template, ...expressions) {
    console.log(template, expressions);
}

foo`foo${1+1}bar` // logs (["foo", "bar"], [2]) but returns `undefined`
```

I.e. if `foo` gets passed only a single argument, the template literal does not contain expressions. However, `foo` would also have to interpolate the static parts with the dynamic parts and return the result (not shown in the above example).