# Why don't ES6 tagged template strings provide the original string template?

Tags: string, ecmascript-6, template-strings

When creating tag functions for template strings in ES6, the function is expected to take a `literals` parameter and a `values` parameter.

```
tagFunc `Hello ${someVar}`;

function tagFunc(literals, ...values){
   // do something
}
```

However, it does not provide access to the original, unevaluated, deconstructed template. Like this for example:

```
tagFunc `Hello ${someVar}`;

function tagFunc(literals, ...values, template){
   // template would be 'Hello ${someVar}'
}
```

or perhaps a `literals.originalTemplate` property to complement `literals.raw`.

Is there a specific reason for this? The best I can think of is that there may be some security implication if the variable names were passed through to a tag function?

Comment: This is better asked somewhere were the ECMAScript devs are present, e.g. https://esdiscuss.org/ .

Comment: There is no such thing as an "unevaluted" or "deconstructed" "template". It's just string interpolation, and you won't get the expressions but just the values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the raw version of a template string in iojs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293928/how-to-get-the-raw-version-of-a-template-string-in-iojs)

Comment: It's not a variable name though, it's a JS expression, it could just as easily be `${1 + 2}`, which wouldn't be usable inside the template function, because it'll have already been evaluated as `3` and passed in.

Comment: Why do you need that? You already have it--you were the one that wrote it. What are you going to do with it? In what format do you expect to get it--a string, but then you'd have to pick it apart yourself, which the engine has already done for you--not getting this.